# Json Result Format in WCF Services

Tags: c#, json, wcf

Good guys afternoon, I have an output on Json format, I need to stay exactly like the picture that is here, but it looks like this, what can I or can I make it display the registration number as top of each the result?

**Format Need**

[image: Format Need]

**Actually Format**

[image: Actually Format]

I get the results through Entity Framework 6; I make the format as specified in [OperationContract]

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
     UriTemplate = "getAllProduct/{value}")]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Articulos")]        
    List<Product> GetAllProduct(string value);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: try removing the attribute  [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Articulos")] . that should give you what you want

Comment: If removing the attribute show me the message "GetAllProductResult" @Ockert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and returning an object `Dictionary<int,Product>`

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "getAllProduct/{value}")]
public System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message GetAllProduct(string value)
{
    Dictionary<int, Product> dict = .......
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have the format needed, Excellent solution